# How to use p:chart in a column of every row with a datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to know if is possible to use a pie chart in a column of every row in a datatable and how to do it in JSF2.2 with primefaces showcase:

https://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/pie.xhtml

My idea is to show a pie chart 100% with a color based in the id into a grid
for every row and a description.

1.blue
2.yellow
3.red.
etc...

I've try the basic code below from the showcase with no success and I have not found any similar example. My xhtml works fine but when I add the pie chart get an error.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "info")
@ViewScoped

public class InfoView implements java.io.Serializable {


@ManagedProperty(value = "#{infoBo}")
private InfoBo infoBo;

private Long id;
private String description; 

private List<Info> listInfo;
private InfoDataModel infoDataModel;    
private Info infoSelected;

private PieChartModel pieModel1;    

 @PostConstruct
public void init() {
    createPieModels();
}

public PieChartModel getPieModel1() {
    return pieModel1;
}

private void createPieModel() {
    createPieModel1();        
}

private void createPieModel1() {
    pieModel1 = new PieChartModel();         
    pieModel1.set("Blue", 100);                 
    pieModel1.setTitle("Blue Simple Pie");
    pieModel1.setLegendPosition("w");
    pieModel1.setShowDataLabels(true);
    pieModel1.setDiameter(150);
}

public getters & setters {

}
```

View xhtlm:

```
<p:dataTable id="datatableInfo" var="varInfo" value="#{Info.infoDataModel}" widgetVar="wdatatableInfo" style="width: 98%"                                             
         paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"                                             
         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"                                             
         selectionMode="single" tableStyle="table-layout:fixed;width:120" >


         <p:column id="id_Reg" headerText="ID" style="width: 2%" sortBy="#{varInfo.id}" >                                    
                <h:outputText value="#{varInfo.idReg}"/>
         </p:column>

         <p:column id="id_description" headerText="Description" style="width: 10%" >             
                <h:outputText value="#{varInfo.description}"/>
         </p:column>

    <p:column id="id_chart" headerText="Chart" style="width: 80%" >             
                <p:chart type="pie" model="#{varInfo.pieModel1}" style="width:40px;height:30px" />
        </p:column>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, chart only appears (in my app) with pieModel1.setLegendPosition("s")